# The difference between two: Like it that-S vs Like that S

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Native speakers often use ``dummy pronoun it'' between *like* and *that*.

I am curious about whether there is any nuance difference between two sentences.

If not why do natives put it?

---

> a. She liked it that her friends boasted about her.
>
> b. She liked that her friends boasted about her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the speaker is trying to do in A is emphasize "she liked it."

The *it* is probably technically ungrammatical if this is really meant as one single phrase.

The "thing" that "she liked" is the entire phrase "that her friends boasted about her.*  So specifying an object *it* for *liked* is redundant and unclear - *it* would normally refer to a noun, but even if it didn't, you wouldn't use *it* to refer to a phrase and then specify the phrase.  That's like saying "Give the money to her my mom."

Now, if two phrases are meant, it's OK:

> She liked it, that her friends boasted about her.

In speaking this, there would be a noticeable pause or lowering of voice pitch (similar to that at the end of a sentence) between *it* and *that*.

Similarly,

> Give the money to her, my mom

is also OK.

I think, but am not sure, that these are examples of [appositive construction](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm).